# HID service not visible

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, hid, gatt

I am working on a Swift app (iOS) that connects to a device via BLE.

I have written some code, managed to connect to my device, managed to get the advertised data but when I scan for the services using the didDiscoverServices method, I only get the Battery and Device information service, not the HID service.
I can see the Device information, Battery, and HID service in the advertise data but not in the didDiscoverServices method.
I can access characteristics of the Battery and Device information in the didDiscoverServices method.
I have read in multiple places that HID is managed by iOS and not by the app.

Is there any way to access the HID service?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no way to access this service. Apple actively filters certain BLE services so you cannot access them via the CoreBluetooth API. In particular, the HID over Gatt service is maintained by the system so you can use your device to enter text etc. but you will be unable to intercept any events in your app.

The aforementioned filtering also applies to the peripheral role. If you try to add the HID over Gatt UUID as a new service to a CBPeripheralManager you will get an error.